# Any way to turn off warning generated in 'use Module' statement in Perl

Tags: perl

I am currently using the `XML::LibXML` module in my Perl script. The `XML::LibXML` module we're currently using on our machines was compiled against a newer version of the `libxml2` library, and the use statement generates the following warning:

```
Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20708, but runtime libxml2 is older 20706
```

The warning does not affect the performance of my script. I've spoken to my supervisor and she says that the error can be completely ignored for our current purposes. Is there any way to temporarily turn off this warning without turning off ALL warnings? I tried to enclose the `use` statement inside of a code block `{}` and turned off warnings with `no warnings;`, but I still got the warning.

Comment: " ... but this did not work." How did it not work? Do you still get the warning, or does something else go wrong?

Comment: You can see the source of the `XML::LibXML` module by typing `perldoc -m XML::LibXML`, which shows that the warning comes from an explicit `warn` call. You can hack the module source (if you can't update it), or you can inhibit the `warn` somehow. (Temporarily redirecting stderr to /dev/null or equivalent should work, but there should be a cleaner way to do it.)

Comment: `local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {};` *should* work, but in my quick experiment it doesn't. It looks like it applies only in the current source file / package / whatever.

Comment: @KeithThompson: did you put it in a `BEGIN` block? because the warning is most probably thrown (? uttered? what is the verb for warnings?) inside the `import` routine.

Comment: I tried temporarily redirecting `sterr` to `/dev/null`, but no luck so far. I'll try to do more research into the `local $SIG{__WARN__}` method you've posted above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can inhibit warnings, even those like this one that are issued as a result of an explicit call to the `warn` function, by setting `$SIG{__WARN__}`.

A simple working example (improved thanks to ysth's comment):

mod.pm:

```
package mod;

sub method {
    print "This is mod::method\n";
}

warn "WE DO NOT WANT THIS WARNING\n";

1;
```

foo.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN {
    local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {};
    require mod;
    mod::->import();
}

warn "Normal warnings work\n";
mod::method();
```

The output is:

```
Normal warnings work
This is mod::method
```

and I've confirmed that commenting out the setting of `$SIG{__WARN__}` causes the "DO NOT WANT" warning to appear.

Comment: `BEGIN` says stop compiling after this block and run it before resuming compiling.  `use` says load this module and run its mainline code and import method before resuming compiling.  so with the use inside the BEGIN block, it still happens before the %SIG assignment is actually run.  `BEGIN { local $SIG...; require mod; mod::->import() }` would work

Comment: @ysth: Thanks, I was hoping someone would come up with an improvement.

Comment: Thank you kind stranger! This is exactly the kind of convenient work-around I was hoping existed for this issue. FYI, `use` still produced the warning, but `require` did not.